# IIS7 - 401.3 Error

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

I'm trying to get a site working on IIS7 with classic ASP and having problems. I've created a directory and added both Network Service and IIS_IUSRS with full control. I've also changed the anonymous authentication to the application pool identity, but still no joy. I really have no idea what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that Classic ASP is installed? It's an extra option which can be here: Control Panel/Programs/Windows Features/Internet Information Services/Www services/Application Development Features/ASP.